# Время окончательного применения свойств CSS

Tags: jquery, css, css3, анимация, css-animation

Я обнаружил, что некоторые свойства CSS (думаю, в первую очередь те, которые отвечают за позиционирование и отображение элементов) применяются с небольшой задержкой (часто способной поломать код).

В моём случае это свойство **opacity** при создании слайд-шоу. пример я максимально упростил, убрал классы и всё лишнее, чтобы минимизировать код.

Следующая функция делает чтобы элемент исчез (моментально), а затем появился (плавно).

```
function fadeIn() {
    var $el=$('div');
    $el.css('transition', '').css('opacity', '0').delay(13)
    .queue(function(next) {
        $(this).css('transition', 'all 2s').css('opacity', '1');
        next(); 
    });
}
```

Всё работает, но delay(13) выглядит как грязный хак (в хроме достаточно delay(0), но в Firefox нужно не меньше 13). А на более медленном ПК нужно будет задержку ещё больше ставить?

Думаю, что происходит следующее: при недостаточно большом **delay** применение **opacity** не успевает произойти - и тут же применяется **transition** (и на моментальном исчезновении можно ставить крест).

Существует ли какое-то красивое решение проблемы? чтобы выполнить определённый код только после того, как свойства CSS "по-настоящему" применятся к элементам?

Answer (score 8):

Когда ты пытаешься менять стили, браузер по возможности оптимизирует перерасчёт и высока вероятность, что набор последовательных действий будет применён единовременно.

Для того, чтобы заставить браузер форсированно применить изменения, нужно получить значение ширины или высоты элемента.

Вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/whpmhwzz/4/

```js
~function () {
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo");

  document.getElementById("to-0").addEventListener("click", function() {
    demo.style.width = 0;
  });

  document.getElementById("to-100").addEventListener("click", function() {
    demo.style.width = "100%";
  });

  document.getElementById("try-force-to-0").addEventListener("click", function() {
    demo.style.transition = "none";
    demo.style.width = "0";
    demo.style.transition = ""; // IE fails to assign null
  });

  document.getElementById("force-to-0").addEventListener("click", function() {
    demo.style.transition = "none";
    demo.style.width = "0";
    getComputedStyle(demo).transition; // No recalculation in FF and IE
    demo.style.transition = "";
  });

  document.getElementById("force-to-0-again").addEventListener("click", function() {
    demo.style.transition = "none";
    demo.style.width = "0";
    getComputedStyle(demo).width;
    demo.style.transition = "";
  });

  document.getElementById("force-to-0-height").addEventListener("click", function() {
    demo.style.transition = "none";
    demo.style.width = "0";
    getComputedStyle(demo).height;
    demo.style.transition = "";
  });

  document.getElementById("force-to-0-fail").addEventListener("click", function() {
    demo.style.transition = "none";
    demo.style.width = "0";
    getComputedStyle(demo); // No recalculation
    demo.style.transition = "";
  });
}();
```

```css
p {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 3s linear;
  height: 2em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button id=to-0>To 0</button>
  <button id=try-force-to-0>Try force to 0</button>
  <button id=force-to-0>Force to 0</button>
  <button id=force-to-0-again>Force to 0 again</button>
  <button id=force-to-0-height>Force to 0 once more</button>
  <button id=force-to-0-fail>Force to 0 fail</button>
  <button id=to-100>To 100</button>
</p>
<div id=demo></div>
```

Comment: Пара уточнений: `getComputedStyle(demo).transition; // No recalculation in FF and IE` не работает, потому что `transition` - это shorthand property. `getComputedStyle().color` уже будет работать. Получать width/height даже немного хуже: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31862081/1026  PS. Про `~function(){}()` не знал, прикольно.

Comment: @VenZell, пробел после унарного оператора? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy это автоматическое форматирование... Я тут ни при чем. :) Я только добавил свойство `margin-top` для `p`

Answer (score 2):

Вы немножко не правильно поняли. Задержка отрисовки страницы происходит из-за тега **script**, то есть из-за **javascript**. Браузер, дойдя до такого тега, останавливает отрисовку DOM и ждёт полной загрузки js-файла. Именно поэтому правильным тоном является конкатенировать js-файлы в один и размещать тег **script** в самом конце **body**. Полная загрузка и отрисовка страницы (картинки, css и т.д.) происходит после события **load**, а не **ready**:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   alert("window is loaded");
});
```

Comment: Вроде все и правильно, но не по теме вопроса.

Comment: @Nickolay быть может я не так понял, на скорую руку прочитав :)