# css анимация при добавлении класса

Tags: jquery, css, css3, анимация, css-animation

Добавляю элементу класс, для которого установлена анимация (`animation`). После добавления анимация включаться не хочет. Включается только если добавлять класс через `setTimeout`. Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/8vqg8gh8/

```js
jQuery('.b').on('click', function() {
 var element = jQuery('.a');
    element.removeClass('a');
    element.addClass('a');
});
```

```css
@keyframes anim {
    0% {width: 0px; height: 0px;}
    100% {width: 100px; height: 100px;}
}
.a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    animation: anim 0.5s;
}
.b {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "a"></div>
<span class = "b">Перезапустить</span>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Время окончательного применения свойств CSS](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433613/%d0%92%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2-css)

Comment: И зачем тут вообще animation, если можно обойтись transition'ом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
jQuery('.b').on('click', function() {
    var element = jQuery('.a');
    element.removeClass('a');
    element.width(); // Force reflow
    element.addClass('a');
});
```

```css
@keyframes anim {
    0% {width: 0px; height: 0px;}
    100% {width: 100px; height: 100px;}
}
.a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    animation: anim 0.5s;
}
.b {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "a"></div>
<span class = "b">Перезапустить</span>
```

Comment: А почему без вычисления ширины элемента с последующим отбрасыванием результата анимация не работает?

Comment: @mymedia, я ж там даже комментарий написал: _"Force reflow"_. Если мы убрали класс и тут же снова добавили, то как бы ничего не изменилось и анимировать нечего. Если же мы убрали класс, спросили у браузера что-то (типа ау, пересчитай что там у тебя сейчас), а потом снова добавили, то теперь уже браузер анимирует то, что изменилось после вопроса.