# Изменение стиля элемента без необходимости в setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, css, анимация, settimeout

Есть код, который создаёт диаграмму с количеством показателей в зависимости от количества аргументов функции. У класса элементов `box` есть CSS-параметр `transition`, который не работает без функции `setTimeout()`.

```js
var graph = document.getElementById('graph-container'),
  box;

function drawGraph() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var box = document.createElement('div')
    box.className = 'box'
    box.style.height = arguments[i] + 'px'
    graph.appendChild(box)
  }
}

var a = document.getElementsByClassName('box')
drawGraph(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
setTimeout(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a[i].style.height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + '%'
  }
}, 0)
```

```css
#graph-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  width: 400px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.box {
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="graph-container"></div>
```

Можно ли обойтись без `setTimeout()` и как это сделать, чтобы был плавный переход между состояниями элементов?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Время окончательного применения свойств CSS](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433613/%d0%92%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2-css)

Comment: А меня одного смущает, что вы сначала выбираете элементы `.box` и только потом их создаете в `drawGraph`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, `getElementsByClassName` даёт живую коллекцию, которая сама синхронизируется с dom'ом при обращении к ней. С другой стороны, это не слишком хорошо для производительности.

Comment: Кстати, random надо умножать на 100, а не на 99.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var graph = document.getElementById('graph-container'),
  box;

function drawGraph() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var box = document.createElement('div')
    box.className = 'box'
    box.style.height = arguments[i] + 'px'
    graph.appendChild(box)
  }
}

var a = document.getElementsByClassName('box')
drawGraph(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
getComputedStyle(a[0]).width;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  a[i].style.height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + '%'
}
```

```css
#graph-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  width: 400px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.box {
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="graph-container"></div>
```