# Объясните механизм работы строчки popup.offsetWidth=popup.offsetWidth;

Tags: javascript

Начинаю обучение фронтенду по материалам [htmlacademy](http://htmlacademy.ru) . Оживляю js-ом тренировочный макет по [ссылке](http://www.kozart.net/layouts/barbershop/index.html).

В скрипте отвечающем за работу формы входа:

```
var link = document.querySelector(".login");
var popup = document.querySelector(".modal-content");
var overlay = document.querySelector(".modal-overlay");
var close = document.querySelector(".modal-content-close");
var login = popup.querySelector("[name = login]");
var password = popup.querySelector("[name = password]");
var form = popup.querySelector("form");
var storage = localStorage.getItem("login");

link.addEventListener("click", function(event){
popup.classList.remove("modal-error");
event.preventDefault();

overlay.classList.add("modal-content-show");
popup.classList.add("modal-content-show");

if(storage){
    login.value = storage;
    password.focus();
}
else {login.focus();}

});

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
if(!login.value || !password.value) {
    event.preventDefault();
    popup.classList.remove("modal-error");
    popup.offsetWidth=popup.offsetWidth;
    popup.classList.add("modal-error");

}
else {localStorage.setItem("login", login.value);
    popup.classList.remove("modal-error");}
});

close.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
popup.classList.remove("modal-content-show");
popup.classList.remove("modal-error");
overlay.classList.remove("modal-content-show");
});

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
if(event.keyCode === 27) {
    if(popup.classList.contains("modal-content-show")){
        popup.classList.remove("modal-content-show");
        popup.classList.remove("modal-error");
        overlay.classList.remove("modal-content-show");
    }
}
});
```

вопрос вызывает строчка `popup.offsetWidth=popup.offsetWidth;`
без нее не работает, очевидно она создает задержку, но как?

Answer (score 3):

Эта строка вызывает reflow. При этом все стили пересчитываются и последующие изменения можно считать как бы с этого момента. Полезно для анимаций.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433721/178988

Answer (score 0):

Эта строчка содержит ширину элемента, включая внутренние отступы (css-свойство padding) и рамку (css-свойство border).

Comment: Вопрос был пор то, зачем нужно присваивать свойство самому себе, а не что оно содержит.