# Найти все теги с изображениями (правило background-image или тег img+src) и собрать их в массив

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Господа, данный скрипт, определяет есть ли на странице теги с правилом css  "background-image" и тег "img" с атрибутом "src" для определения их значения.

Смысл в том, что бы создать массив из всех картинок или фото на странице и использовать их потом или для слайдера или использовать это для чего-нибудь другого.

Вопрос, можно ли код упростить и сделать его более компактным и грамотно ли я подошел к вопросу?

весь код проверять не надо. А что надо описано в js в комментариях.

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
const allBlocks = document.body.querySelectorAll('*');
const img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
const dataImages = document.getElementsByClassName('dataImages');
var arraydataImagesValue = [];
for (let i = 0; i < allBlocks.length; i++) {
  /*тут я определяю у каких узлов в css  прописано правило background-image */
  if ((getComputedStyle(allBlocks[i]).getPropertyValue('background-image') !== "none")) {
    /*и присваиваю этому узлу атрибут data-images и значение background-image*/
    allBlocks[i].setAttribute('data-images', getComputedStyle(allBlocks[i])['background-image']);
  }
}
for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {

  /*тут я определяю у каких узлов имеется атрибут src */
  if (img[i].hasAttribute('src')) {
    /*и присваиваю этому узлу атрибут data-images и  значение src*/
    img[i].setAttribute('data-images', 'url(' + img[i].getAttribute('src') + ')');
  }
}
for (let i = 0; i < allBlocks.length; i++) {
  /*тут я определяю у каких узлов имеется атрибут data-images */
  if (allBlocks[i].hasAttribute('data-images')) {
    /*и присваиваю этому узлу class dataImages */
    allBlocks[i].classList.add('dataImages')
  }
}
/*
Больше всего меня интересует, правильно ли я подошел к самой идее и правильно 
ли я сделал используя три цикла или можно бвло бы обойтись меньшим 
количеством циклов.

В общем, одним словом, какие у меня ошибки в логике в синтаксисе и в понимании программирования на js
*/

/*код ниже в инспекции не нуждяется, это на скорую руку для 
визуального отображения результата моей идеи,
но если есть замечания, буду рад узнать о своих ошибка,
можно даже грубо, но объективно*/
for (let i = 0; i < dataImages.length; i++) {
  arraydataImagesValue[i] = dataImages[i].getAttribute('data-images');


  //===========================================
  let moduleWrapper = div.cloneNode(true);
  moduleWrapper.setAttribute('id', 'moduleWrapper');
  //===========================================
  let fotoModuleWrapper = div.cloneNode(true);
  fotoModuleWrapper.setAttribute('id', 'fotoModuleWrapper');
  //===========================================
  let fotoModule = div.cloneNode(true);
  fotoModule.setAttribute('id', 'fotoModule');
  //===========================================
  let closedBlock = div.cloneNode(true);
  closedBlock.setAttribute('id', 'closedBlock');
  //===========================================




  dataImages[i].addEventListener('click', () => {


    document.body.appendChild(moduleWrapper);
    moduleWrapper.setAttribute('id', 'moduleWrapperActive');
    moduleWrapper.appendChild(fotoModuleWrapper);
    fotoModuleWrapper.setAttribute('id', 'fotoModuleWrapperActive');
    fotoModuleWrapper.appendChild(fotoModule);
    fotoModule.setAttribute('id', 'fotoModuleActive');
    fotoModule.style.backgroundImage = dataImages[i].getAttribute('data-images');
    fotoModuleWrapper.appendChild(closedBlock);

  })


  closedBlock.addEventListener('click', () => {
    fotoModuleWrapper.removeChild(closedBlock);
    fotoModule.setAttribute('id', 'fotoModule');
    fotoModuleWrapper.removeChild(fotoModule);
    fotoModuleWrapper.setAttribute('id', 'fotoModuleWrapper');
    moduleWrapper.removeChild(fotoModuleWrapper);
    moduleWrapper.setAttribute('id', 'moduleWrapper');
    document.body.removeChild(moduleWrapper);
  })

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all .3s;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #262626;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: #012727;
  color: white;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: baseline;
}

.images {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 180px;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  background: #012727;
  color: white;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 25px;
}

.images#bg1 {
  background-image: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_5orOplFcJxA/S_bQVXtyrXI/AAAAAAAAB8k/an2ZU5-q21g/s1600/hayvan-resimleri-5.jpg);
}

.images#bg2 {
  background-image: url(https://file.sadecehaber.com/fotograf/fotograf_7eeafa862dffd9e3faa719b04748217d11f3a38a.jpg);
}

.images#bg3 {
  background-image: url(http://www.zwalls.ru/pic/201309/1920x1200/zwalls.ru-4399.jpg);
}

.images#bg4 {
  background-image: url(https://wallperz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/11/wallperz.com-20161111130034.jpg);
}

#moduleWrapper {
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

#moduleWrapperActive {
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

#closedBlock {
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 6;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  right: -30px;
  top: -30px;
  background-image: url(https://www.shareicon.net/download/2017/01/17/872777_close_512x512.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

#fotoModuleWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

#fotoModuleWrapperActive {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 700px;
  height: 540px;
  left: calc(50% - 350px);
  top: calc(50% - 270px);
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

#fotoModule {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
}

#fotoModuleActive {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  background: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>

    <div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>

    <div class="images" id="bg1"></div>
    <div class="images" id="bg2"></div>
    <div class="images" id="bg3"></div>

  </main>
  <div class="images" id="bg4"></div>
  <footer>

    <img class="images" src="https://animalplanet4u.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/the-best-top-desktop-lion-wallpapers-hd-lion-wallpaper-1.jpeg" alt="">
    <img class="images" src="https://animalplanet4u.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/lion-wallpaper-8.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="images" src="https://get.wallhere.com/photo/animals-wildlife-big-cats-whiskers-leopard-Jaguar-jaguars-fauna-mammal-vertebrate-cat-like-mammal-168017.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="images" src="https://get.wallhere.com/photo/black-animals-dog-white-flowers-daisies-puppies-Labrador-Retriever-puppy-mammal-vertebrate-dog-like-mammal-dog-breed-stabyhoun-retriever-flat-coated-retriever-231937.jpg" alt="">
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: ошибки в синтаксисе покажет консоль. В логике ошибка: нет нужды делать три цикла, если можно обойтись одним

Comment: @Grundy, не согласен.

Comment: Grundy, пытался, не получилось, будь другом покажи как...  буду признателен

Comment: @Qwertiy, с чем? он же все равно по **всем** элементам бежит вначале

Comment: @Grundy, ну в принципе в данной реализации можно. Но вообще, reflow. А ещё я бы всё равно так делать не стал :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, что за reflow? :)

Comment: @Grundy, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433721/178988 & http://stackoverflow.com/a/31862081/1026

Comment: @NickVolynkin, у меня из-за не правильных двух вопросов  и 
 их названий, были проблемы, не мог задавать вопросы...  честно не соображу как изменить, что бы мне опять отрицательный статус вопросу не влепили...   будь другом, прости за наглость, измени сам, покажи как бы ты назвал, просто не соображу как, хотите верьте хотите нет...

Comment: Нород, спасибо всем

Comment: @Air ну вот как-то так. Понимаете принцип?

Comment: @Air для сравнения — это как позвонить в скорую помощь и сказать «здравствуйте, я вам звоню, потому что у меня проблема и я хочу чтобы мне оказали срочную медицинскую помощь». Так можно и кровью истечь, пока объявляешь свои намерения. Лучше сразу к сути переходить. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, сообразил, благодарю...

Comment: )))))))))))))))))))

Comment: @Air написать что ли на Мете инструкцию по заголовкам...

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я поддерживаю всеми руками и ногами за......  я после этих двух, с  отрицательным статусом, вопросов, уже боюсь лишние движения делать)))   много чего читал, суть понимаю, но у каждого вопроса своя суть, а когда голова забита решением самого вопроса, то еще и думать как его правильно сформулировать,  хотя, правильный вопрос, уже половина ответа, но все же...

Comment: @Air прямо сегодня я точно это не напишу. Пока что рекомендую прочитать http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65751/discussion-between-air-and-nick-volynkin).

Comment: @Grundy, будь другом, отобрази, как бы ты изменил все в одном цикле,  я часа четыре бился, у меня не получилось...  не смотря, что Qwertiy многое разъяснил, твое мнение тоже очень интересно... заранее благодарю

Comment: @Air, ответил в чате

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> .setAttribute('data-images'

Горяздо лучше созранять данные в скрипте, а не изменять страницу.

> /*тут я определяю у каких узлов в css  прописано правило background-image */

Псевдоэлементы не учитываются.

> ```
> const img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
> const dataImages = document.getElementsByClassName('dataImages');
> ```

Эффективнее будет использовать `querySelectorAll` в нужном месте. Живые коллекции гораздо затратнее при обращении по имени.

> ```
> if (img[i].hasAttribute('src')) {
> ```

1. Возможно, это стоит поместить в селектор.
2. Как насчёт [`srcset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)?
3. Как насчёт [`picture`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)?
4. Обращение к `src` лучше писать через свойство: `img[i].src`.

> ```
> let moduleWrapper = div.cloneNode(true);
> moduleWrapper.setAttribute('id', 'moduleWrapper');
> ```

Тут в цикле создаётся куча элементов с одинаковыми id. Перечитал внимательнее - вроде в dom они одновременно не окажутся, но в таком случае тебе нужен только один, а не все.

> ```
> moduleWrapper.setAttribute('id', 'moduleWrapper');
> ```

`id` тоже лучше устанавливать через свойство: `moduleWrapper.id = ...`.

> ```
> moduleWrapper.setAttribute('id', 'moduleWrapperActive');
> ```

Менять id странно.

> ```
> dataImages[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
> ```

А то если элемент расположен так, что его нельзя кликнуть? Либо на нём уже есть обработчик, который отменит распространение события? И снова псевдоэлементы.

Comment: Как насчёт srcset?  Как насчёт picture?  ты правильно подметил, просто, мне бы хотелось этот скрипт использовать, даже там, где не я писал разметку, как бы универсальный подход...  но если бы я писал html  я бы конечно использовал picture...

Comment: на счет псевдоэлементов... если я правильно понял, то ты имеешь ввиду, что бы, если у псевдоэлемента тоже есть "background-image", то чтобы и он учитывался?

Comment: @Air, я имею в виду, что картинки 1. в тегах picture, 2. в img через srcset и 3. фоном псевдоэлементов не учитываются скриптом.

Comment: все сообрази, точно, надо еще добавить "picture"...  и псевдоэлементы тоже захватить...  век живи, век учись.........))))))

Comment: Qwertiy, я когда ввожу собачку "@", обычно выводятся имена участников, можно вставить впереди, твоего  нет))))))  почему?

Comment: @Air, потому что в этих комментах нас только двое, а я - автор поста. Если кто-то ещё добавится, то я появлюсь в списке.

Comment: а, вот оно, что...

Comment: справился со всеми твоими замечаниями, не могу найти способ с псевдоэлементами справиться, подскажи чего почитать... и где найти

Comment: @Air, у [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) есть второй параметр. Пример с mdn: `var result = getComputedStyle(h3, ':after').content;`

Comment: ок, спасибо....